# Doesn't display the font you added via @font-face

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Looked similar questions and not found the answer. Chrome Browser ver.52.
Added to website font. In the base css-file added the code with my structure:

```css
../src/
├── apps
├── base
├── common
│   ├── font
│   │   └── open-sans
│   │       └── font.ttf
│   │       └── font.eot
│   │       └── font.woff
│   ├── static
│   │   └── css
│   │       └── base.css
│   ├── templates
│   └── views
```

@font-face variant, which i'm used

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open_sansbold';
  src: url('../../font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../../font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../../font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../../font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../../font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#open_sansbold') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open_sansbold';
  src: url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#open_sansbold') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

But the font is not applied to the element:

```css
.element__symbol {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  font: bold 15pt open_sansbold;
}
```

When inspecting the page gives open_sansbold, but uses a serif font. console without error

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Added project structure

Comment: not found font. why? Request URL:127.0.0.1:8000/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfo‌​nt.woff

Answer (score 1):

Probably the paths to the fonts are incorrect. Chrome shows 2 errors on the console window. Can you post the console errors?

Comment: yep, i think about it. but i haven't console error and i haven't font on sources

Comment: on the image you posted, theres 2 errors on the chrome console. Just click the "Console" tab to see what the errors are

Comment: oh, yes, it's another error. now my console is clean

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the correct answer you're looking for, but if you're just trying to load `Open Sans Bold`, use google fonts.

Here is a html snippet which allows you to load the font in.

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700" rel="stylesheet">`

Here is a css snippet which allows you to load the font in.

`@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700';`

Then with your css, try this;

```
.element__symbol {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15pt;
}
```

Google fonts is a highly reliable way of loading in fonts, and a way that I do suggest using if at all possible.

Comment: yep, i tried it, it's ok, but i prefer have local font on my server

Comment: I mean fair enough, but using Google font will almost definitely be faster